# Issue tracker where I can assign an issue to a passer-by who is not a core member

Tags: gratis, issue-tracker

## Requirement

I am looking for an issue tracker where I can assign an issue to a passer-by who is not a core member of the project.

- It must be easy to see what issues are currently assigned to a particular user.
- Free for at least 50 core members and infinite passer-by contributors.
- Anybody can comment on any issue, without needing our approval. They might have to create an account on the platform though.

## Why GitHub is not a solution

On GitHub issues can only be assigned to core members of the project (and making everyone a core member is not safe as core members have big powers such as removing other people's comments).

## Context

Our open source project is very popular with students who are looking for a small task to accomplish, and we indeed have hundred of small issues that need to be fixed.

Nearly everyday, a user comments on an issue `I want to work on this!` even though another user is already working on it. Often two persons send a pull request for the same issue. We created an `assigned` tag but it is vague as it does not say explicitly who is assigned, and some users who have a lot of issues assigned to them struggle to keep track of what issues are assigned to them, recently a user thought she had finished all issues assigned to her whereas she actually had 3 left.